# ¿Porqué le pasa esto a mi código cuando lo proceso?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, visual-studio

Cuando el archivo con el código que escribí con las reglas de javascript me lo compila babel, a algunos nombres de mis variables le agrega _ como ahora a la variable **elemento**, el problema es que la consola marca indefinido, así que cuando le agrego _ a los nombres que restan que no se las agregó ya me marca definido y el código se ejecuta perfectamente.

```
//Usando javascript ES6    
'use strict';

const categorias = ['Acción', 'Comedia', 'Aventura'];
const peliculas = ['La vida es bella', 'La verdad duela', 'Gran torre'];

const cine = [categorias, peliculas];

// console.log(cine[0][1]);
// console.log(cine[1][2]);


let elemento;

do{
    let elemento = prompt('Introduce tu pelicula:');
    peliculas.push(elemento);
}while(elemento != 'ACABAR');


peliculas.pop();
peliculas[0] = undefined;

//añadir nuevo elemento

console.log(peliculas);


//babel
'use strict';

var categorias = ['Acción', 'Comedia', 'Aventura'];
var peliculas = ['La vida es bella', 'La verdad duela', 'Gran torre'];
var cine = [categorias, peliculas]; // console.log(cine[0][1]);
// console.log(cine[1][2]);

var elemento;

do {
  var _elemento = prompt('Introduce tu pelicula:');

  peliculas.push(_elemento);
} while (elemento != 'ACABAR');

peliculas.pop();
peliculas[0] = undefined; //añadir nuevo elemento

console.log(peliculas);
```

Comment: cuando pones "use strict" no estás transpilando nada. Le estás diciendo que interprete el código en modo estricto, cuya única consecuencia practica es la manera como se interpreta `this`. (las otras implicancias van en la línea de considerar errores algunos defectos que se pasan por alto sin el modo estricto) . Imagino que te refieres a que te imprime algo en pantalla que no es lo esperado?

Answer (score 1):

Primero de todo tienes que entender que `babel` es un compilador para compilar JS moderno (a partir de ES6) a ES5 que es la versión que actualmente es la "standard" que implementan  la mayoría de los navegadores.

Aunque las nuevas versiones de JS tienen un alto porcentaje de adopción por parte de los navegadores hay ciertas funcionalidades que aun no soportan. Puedes ver [en esta web](https://caniuse.com/) las características soporta cada navegador actualmente.

Y una de estas nuevas características es la introducción de dos tipos nuevos de variables
[const](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/const) y [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/let).

Lo más importante que tienes que entender que estas variables son `block-scoped`, es decir, que solo existen en el ámbito del bloque donde se han declarado.

`const` no se puede inicializar sin valor y no se puede reasignar(hay algunas excepciones).

Y en tu caso estas declarando 2 veces la variable `elemento` con `let` en 2 ámbitos(scope) distintos.

```
// gloabl scope
let elemento;

do{
    // block scope
    let elemento = prompt('Introduce tu pelicula:');
    peliculas.push(elemento);
} while(elemento != 'ACABAR');
```

Y esto cuando es compilado por babel es traducido en 2 variables distintas porque estas creando la variable `elemento` en `do-while` por eso le añade el `_` para indicar que es otra variable para no crear colisión con la variable que está en `global scope`.

```
var elemento; // hace referencia a la variable que está scope global

do {
  // variable que está block scope
  var _elemento = prompt('Introduce tu pelicula:');

  peliculas.push(_elemento);
} while (elemento != 'ACABAR');
```

Para arreglar tu error puedes declarar la variable solo una vez y reasignar en cada loop del `do-while`.

```
let elemento;

do{
    elemento = prompt('Introduce tu pelicula:');
    peliculas.push(elemento);
} while(elemento != 'ACABAR');
```